# How to change delphi firemonkey Speed button Lookup style at run time

Tags: delphi, button, firemonkey

I am having Speed button Which is linked to MultiView as Master button . I need to show different Lookup styles when multiview is selected and not selected. How should i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass the SpeedButton and override the ApplyStyle procedure in order to change the style on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just set style through *MasterButton.StyleLookup*. The best place for it are *TMultiView.OnShown* and *TMultiView.OnHidden*;